# Business layer to handle broken database relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, design-patterns, database-design

There are database tables which store the copies of data and unfortunately the original author of these tables didn't design in using relationship (FK, Guid, etc.) in referring to the data when needed but actually copied over data themselves to other tables.. maybe that was for reducing overhead and making easier to retrieve all necessary information in one query.

And now there comes issues obviously because another person wrote code such, let's say 'data 1' in 'table A' can be modified by user, when that 'data 1' is also in 'table B' and 'table C'.  At least it's not totally hopeless because there is another column in 'table A', let's say 'key 1', that can be used paired with 'data 1' when copied over to 'table B' and 'table C' so at least the relationship is not lost when changed by user.

Currently the code uses asp.net MVC pattern and I understand that the fix is probably depending on how code is written and all that, however does anyone know well known fix for issue like this?  Design pattern, architecture, etc.  Right now redesigning database schema is not an option and needs to be backward compatible, meaning should be able to handle old formats without keys, but the plan is updating already stored data to have keys eventually.

Comment: Option1. You would probably need on a per table basis, what other tables have the same data, i,e TableA may have data that is present in both TableB and TableC, so for TableA, the dependency-list is TableB, TableC. This would need to be evaluated for all of your tables. Once this is done, any time you update the main table, you'll have to update the tables from its dependency list - this could probably done through a stored proc on the DB server. Option2. Have a DB level daily procedure to walk through all inserts/updates from the day and update the related tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design pattern most suitable to this is "[Anti-corruption layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used)". The intention is to isolate the problems by building a layer around it which allows other systems to act as if everything were normal.

In an MVC app, that would almost certainly need to live between your "model" code and the persistence layer. For instance, you may introduce a method called "Save_to_business_concept_A"; this would then manipulate your tables A, B and C according to the current logic.

Once your application routes through the anti-corruption layer, you can refactor.

Comment: Here is some addendum based on the answer above. ;)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer